# CoffeeScript.compile() list of accepted parameters

Tags: compiler-construction, coffeescript

Using http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js directly, what are the parameters accepted by the function compile() ?

So far, I can see two parameters:

1. The CoffeeString to compile into JavaScript
2. An object used as options for the compiler

Is there other parameters?

What are the supported options for the second parameter? So far, I only managed to make bare: on/off work. Is there something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not read the [literate source](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/coffee-script.html) and not the minified one? I can see:

- `header`: do we surround it with `"// Generated by CoffeeScript blah blah"`?
- `filename`: for reporting error messages
- `sandbox`: a context to execute code in for `eval`
- `modulename`: the name for the created module when evalling

The same options are then used with the name `o` in [`nodes.coffee`](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/nodes.html), and some state is passed around in it from there on.